# How to remove bracket from array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How can I remove the bracket and insert comma(,) from an array?

**My code output: ($var_array)**

```
Array ( [06] => Body Weight Squat [04] => Body Weight Squat )
```

**Expectation: ($var_new_array)**

```
array(
    06  => 'Body Weight Squat',
    04  => 'Body Weight Squat' 
)
```

code:

```
$data['year'] = $year; 
$data['month'] = $month;  
$query = $this->daysmodel->fetch_exercises_byForDate($year.'-'.$month.'-');
$data['query']=$query; 
$array[] = [];  
foreach ($query as $row) {
    $date=$row->for_date; 
    $array[date('d', strtotime($date))] = $row->menu_name  ;
} 
$newArray= $this->array_flatten($array); 
print_r( $newArray);// Array ( [06] => Body Weight Squat [04] => Body Weight Squat )  
$this->load->view('calender/myCalender', $data);
```

I am trying for this [Passing Data to your Calendar Cells](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html#passing-data-to-your-calendar-cells)

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: And what's the problem with the code?

Comment: @PratikButani updated code

Comment: @user202729 Yes i have the problem with the code. It's not giving output as per my expectation.

Comment: the brackets are just syntax that print_r uses to indicate an index, they are not part of the index - look up the function in the php documentation, it is often quite good ;)

Comment: @cypherabe also if you notice it does not have comma(,) between array elements

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php print_r, like var_dump, is a helper / debuging function to display values during development, not something to use in production. the output is formatted to visualize the structure, it does not directly represent the source code ( `print_r([0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']) // will display something like array ( [0] => a _linebreak_ [1] => b) ` - i think you search at the wrong place, most likely the calender expects different data in the array - and you pass `$data` , not `$new_array`, is that right?

Comment: It's the same thing.

Comment: If you want to output in valid PHP syntax, use `var_export`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove

```
$array[] = [];
```

and use `$array[]` directly.

It will work definitely.

Comment: Thanks! No it didn't work